# Make a bat file that creates a txt file in a defined format

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a bat file that creates a txt file with this format:

```
"

[date]  
2013/29/07 
10:38:00 

"
```

The code doesn't work with bat file, only when I put it in the cmd manual with copy-paste:

```
echo [date]  > e:\TAG.txt
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %i in ('date /t') do ( echo %k/%j/%i >> e:\TAG.txt goto :eof)
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %i in ('time /t') do echo %i:%j:00 >> e:\TAG.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

in Batchfiles, double your % in for-loops:

```
echo [date]  > e:\TAG.txt
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do ( echo %%k/%%j/%%i >> e:\TAG.txt goto :eof)
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=: " %%i in ('time /t') do echo %%i:%%j:00 >> e:\TAG.txt
```

(single % for commandline, double %% in batchfiles - but only in for-loops)

Comment: thanks,and if i want a text file with the contact " 2009.08.18 12:12:12 "   how can i do the for loop for one line ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `%` with `%%` within batch files.

You don't need `goto :eof` inside for. Even if you needed, you must uses `&` between two commands.

In time part,  you don't need 4 arguments, just 2.

Consider also using `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` instead of calling `TIME /T` and `DATE /T`:

```
echo [date]  > e:\TAG.txt
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do echo %%k/%%j/%%i >> e:\TAG.txt
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=: " %%i in ("%time%") do echo %%i:%%j:00 >> e:\TAG.txt
```

EDIT: for single line:

```
echo [date]  > e:\TAG.txt
for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%/%time::=/%") do echo %%k/%%j/%%i %%l:%%m:%%n >> e:\TAG.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add start to the beginning of the line.

The contents of your batch file should be like this:

```
start for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %i in ('date /t') do echo %k/%j/%i >> e:\TAG.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This technique eliminates problems with padding and different locales/computer settings.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

>e:\TAG.txt echo [date]
>>e:\TAG.txt echo %yyyy%/%dd%/%mm%
>>e:\TAG.txt echo %hh%:%min%:%sec%
```